# Render error when using swr within react component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am currently creating a blog and I am trying to add a viewcount to my blogposts.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json())

export default function ViewCounter({
  slug,
  addView = false,
}: {
  slug: string
  addView?: boolean
}) {
  console.log('ViewCounter', slug)
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher)
  const viewCount = new Number(data?.total)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ViewCounter useEffect', slug, addView)
    const registerView = () =>
      fetch(`/api/views/${slug}`, {
        method: 'POST',
      })

    if (addView) {
      registerView()
    }
  }, [slug])

  // return `${viewCount > 0 ? viewCount.toLocaleString() : '–––'} views`
  return (
    <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        className="h-5 w-5"
        // viewBox="0 0 48 48"
        // viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="currentColor"
      >
        <path d="M942.2 486.2C847.4 286.5 704.1 186 512 186c-192.2 0-335.4 100.5-430.2 300.3a60.3 60.3 0 0 0 0 51.5C176.6 737.5 319.9 838 512 838c192.2 0 335.4-100.5 430.2-300.3 7.7-16.2 7.7-35 0-51.5zM512 766c-161.3 0-279.4-81.8-362.7-254C232.6 339.8 350.7 258 512 258c161.3 0 279.4 81.8 362.7 254C791.5 684.2 673.4 766 512 766zm-4-430c-97.2 0-176 78.8-176 176s78.8 176 176 176 176-78.8 176-176-78.8-176-176-176zm0 288c-61.9 0-112-50.1-112-112s50.1-112 112-112 112 50.1 112 112-50.1 112-112 112z"></path>
      </svg>
      {viewCount}
    </span>
  )
}
```

When I add this component to my blog post I get the following error and I don't know why:
`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

When removing swr and inserting a pre defined value the component does render.

[The exact error I get when I try to render the component inside a blog post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC0Zn.png)

Comment: Hey there! In your fetcher function, can you please console.log the output of the call so we can see what the data structure looks like before attempting to compute the viewCount?

Comment: Hi thanks for a fast reply, while I could do this, it  wont work. Since when I add this component to my react app it just crasher when it is trying to render it, so it does not even log anything inside the component. I can make a call to the API via postman, the returned structure is as follows `{"total":34}`. I also opened up the repo, which might be easier to debug, thanks for your help once again! @AmitMaraj